# URL Encoding and Decoding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass URL and my code is:

```
MyUrl = "http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=" + Server.UrlEncode
        (DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")) + "&ProductName="
        + Server.UrlEncode(productName) + "";

mail.Body += "<a href=" + MyUrl + ">Demo Download</a>";
```

But still I'm getting output like:

> http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=12-Apr-2013&ProductName=Otja

So what is wrong with my code and how to decode it on `download.aspx`?

Comment: What output do you expect and what is the input?

Comment: i want encoded output perticulat in  DateTime  it is so important

Comment: You have a bug at `"<a href=" + MyUrl + ">` that you have forget to enclose the href as `"<a href=\"" + MyUrl + "\">`. After that the encode is done, I do not know why you did not make step by step debug to see what you really get inside the code, and not what you see on the render

Comment: Format `12-Apr-2013` is perfectly valid for URLs, what's your problem about it??

Comment: Aren't you using one too many `M`s? (`dd-MM-yyyy` instead of `dd-MMM-yyyy`)

Comment: i m using this for whether the user is download software after 2 days or not  so it is important to encode this

Comment: `MMM` is abbreviated name of month. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Once again, `11-Apr-2013` IS VALID URL PART, there is nothing to encode! Do you really understand what does it mean?

Comment: Purvang, are you trying to encode "-" which is a valid part of any uri or do you want to encrypt the date to something that the end user cannot make out when looking at it?

Answer (score 9):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` from `System.Web` namespace.

[HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method : MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have given a specific format for datetime which (dd-MMM-yy), there is nothing in this string which should be encoded by UrlEncode function.

What i am trying to say can be explained by trying the code below
    Response.Redirect("~/Test.aspx" + Server.UrlEncode(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:MMM:yyyy")));