# DateTime Error in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing an application in which I pass one URL on `inquiry.aspx` page and that URL will send a message to the user's email address.

That URL looks like:

```
mail.Body += string.Format("<a href=\"http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period="
                   + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh mm")
                   + "&ProductName=" + productName + "\">Demo Download</a>");
```

Now I'm retrieving this to the pageload event of `download.aspx` page. My code is:

```
string PName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string;
string myDate = Request.QueryString["period"] as string;

DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
int day1, day2;
day1 = dt1.Day;
day2 = dt2.Day;
TimeSpan variable = dt2 - dt1;
if (day1!=day2)
{
    //Response.Write("Download time is expired now");
    lblmsg.Visible = true;
    lblmsg.Text = "Download time is expired now";
}
else
{
    lblmsg.Visible = true;
    lblmsg.Text = "U can Still Download";
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

My output URL after user clicking on that link from his email id looks like:

```
http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=11-04-2013%2006%2036&ProductName=Otja
```

Here datetime is used for condition that after same day means mail is send to user today and today only he can download. Tommorrow onward it will show message that you are not able to download software now. So that is the reason to pass datetime on URL, but I'm getting error. Please someone help me it's required badly.

Comment: you'll need to parse that string.

Comment: but how sir i tried it already  still geting the same error

Comment: What about the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947214/url-encoding-and-decoding did not help?

Comment: No sir  not atalll  thats  why i m asking again ...

Comment: You need to `Encode` the date or decode when you parse it

Comment: Not an answer, but... wouldn't users simply alter the url by hand, so they can download anyway?

Comment: @purvangpandya look at `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: i did that also  result is null  actually time of retriving that string i m getting null value

Comment: Try taking the spaces out of your DateTime by formatting it with `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyyThh:mm")`

Comment: @C.Evenhuis   sir my next step is urlencoding  but first i want solution for this

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact?

Comment: DStanley sir what is that T after yyyy

Comment: In your code and message to a potential user, please do not spell "you" as "U". Seriously.

Comment: Why not just `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")`? And then `TryParseExact` it back?

Comment: sir how can i use TryParseExact?

Comment: @purvangpandya it's just a placeholder specifying that the remaining digits represent the time.  You can then parse it with `DateTime.ParseExact("dd-MM-yyyyThh:mm")`

Comment: it is also not working sir

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try.

first and foremost change your Date format to Universal Date format and not regional. Assume you are using .net web application, I have seen issues where client execution is different for server.

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

secondly, your datetime format string is not quite right, i.e. missing colon between hour and min. Also if you are trying the said format you must specify your TT or 24 hour. At the end of the say your format would look as follows

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt
```

or

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
```

in addition the above you may want to use date -compare

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate).Date;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now.Date;
if(dt1 != dt2)
{
//...
}
else
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh mm")` when creating the URL, you should use the same format string when parsing it:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd-MM-yyyy hh mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Best practice requires you to also pass the culture when creating the URL: 
`DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

By the way, you should not pass the date in URL in your code sample. Instead you would store the date together with a token in database and pass that token instead. Alternatively you could encrypt the date. The problem is that the recipient is able to change the date and thus overriding your checks for download availability.

Comment: @Knagis sir okk i have generated one random number  and  user's entrydate both are  store in database  now as per your comment i want to generate token and wan to send it to user's mail  so  sir how i can generate this token pls give some idea

Comment: That random number would be your token.